# "Prompt Label" in Custom Intent for WidgetKit widget

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit

What does "Prompt Label" change in a custom intent for a configurable WidgetKit widget?

[image: Prompt Label]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prompt will be shown in the widget configuration interface, above the list of dynamic options. It’s not required, but may be a good place to provide a little extra context or explain anything that isn’t obvious, like if multiple options can be selected.

[image]